# ProxyPassReverse does not keep correct protocol while redirecting

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, virtuoso

I have set up a Virtuoso server that serves Linked Data using content negotiation. The server is served through a reverse proxy Apache server and may be queried using `http` or `https`.

```
http://public.server.org/myapp      --> http://private.local.domain:1234/
https://public.server.org/myapp     --> http://private.local.domain:1234/
```

The Virtuoso server then performs content negotiation and redirects to `/describe?...`

I have no problem when accessing the public server through `http`. The redirection takes place and content is retrieved.

However, when I access the public server though `https`, the redirection sends me to `http://public.server.org/describe?...` (that is `HTTP`, not `HTTPS`).

I'm expecting to be redirected to `https://public.server.org/describe?...` (with the same protocol as the original query).

My configuration is:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.yyy.zzz.ttt:80>
  ServerName public.server.org
  ProxyPass /myapp              http://localhost:8890/myapp
  ProxyPassReverse /myapp       http://localhost:8890/myapp

  ProxyRequests Off

  <Location /describe>
    ProxyPass               http://localhost:8890/describe
    ProxyPassReverse        /describe
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost xxx.yyy.zzz.ttt:443>
  ServerName public.server.org
  ProxyPass /myapp              http://localhost:8890/myapp
  ProxyPassReverse /myapp       http://localhost:8890/myapp

  ProxyRequests Off

  <Location /describe>
    ProxyPass               http://localhost:8890/describe
    ProxyPassReverse        /describe
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Is it possible for apache to correctly reverse the proxy in order to maintain the original query protocol while redirecting?

Comment: I tried to use "ProxyPreserveHost On" directive but this changed nothing at all. Indead, using mod_forensic, I see that the Host field gives the extrernal host name but the protocol is not kept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging with `dumpio` and Apache error logs, I think I found the problem.

#### What happened?

First, my configuration was incorrect. At another place I did not transcribe here, I had a `ProxyPreserveHost On` directive that was active. Hence, the configuration worked but for wrong reasons.

Apache was keeping the Host and Virtuoso used this host. Hence, when sending a redirect to `/describe...`, Virtuoso was redirecting to `http://`**`public.server.org`**`/describe...` instead of my expected `http://`**`localhost:8890`**`/describe...`

Hence, the redirection was not captured by the `ProxyPassReverse` directives and passed unchanged to the client (and it worked). The problem being that the redirection was always done through `http`, regardless of the original query scheme.

#### Solution

I decided to drop the `ProxyPreserveHost On` directive and rely on a correct `ProxyPassReverse` directive.

For an unknown reason, I could not figure out the correct setting inside the `Location`, hence I used the settings:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.yyy.zzz.ttt:443>
  ServerName public.server.org
  ProxyPass /myapp              http://localhost:8890/myapp
  ProxyPassReverse /myapp       http://localhost:8890/myapp

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost Off # To avoid problems if it is set On elsewhere.

  ProxyPass /describe http://localhost:8890/describe
  ProxyPassReverse /describe http://localhost:8890/describe
</VirtualHost>
```

*Note:* I only changed the `https` settings as the `http` ones were functioning somehow (hence the `http` `virtualhost` still uses `ProxyPreserveHost On` and no `ProxyPassReverse`

Comment: You should accept your answer, so this question shows as answered...

Comment: @TailTed Done... Thanks for the editing of both question and answer.